# About overriding toString() method in Java

Tags: java, oop, overriding, tostring

I am watching a video that is trying to override the toString() method in Java, as following

And I am curious about this line of code :

```
returnString += items[i].toString();
```

It seems that the `toString()` here is still the one of Object class.

Why won't this line result in a recursion of the new method I am defining?

That is to say, how do I know which method would it be for the method written inside a new method I am trying to override?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String returnString = "{";

    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i += 1) {
        returnString += items[i].toString();
        returnString += ", ";
    }
    returnString += items[size-1];
    returnString += "}";
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: I guess items[i] is of a different class, or at least it doesn't reference the same items. Therefore it either calls a different method or the recursion is finite.

Answer (score 1):

If `items` is array of another class so this line calls to the `toString()` from the other class.
If `items` is an array of current class, the recursion will stop when the `array.length == 0` or will be an infinity recursion (that will throw an `StackOferflowException`).